# How to get the gallery images path in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

By using following code I am getting image path in 4.4.4 but, when I am using it in lollipop 5.0.1, it is not working.

```
String[] proj = {
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA,
        };

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
        this,  MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);        

        Cursor imageCursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
```

Comment: Check this answer of so.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424624/using-cursorloader-with-loadermanager-to-retrieve-images-from-android-apps

Comment: Bear in mind that there is no requirement that `MediaStore` give you a path to a file that you can use. After all, the file may be on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), which you cannot access on Android 4.4 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

Start the loader manager by invoking getSupportLoaderManager when it is needed.

```
@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Action canceled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else { 
            Toast.makeText(this, "Action failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
    } 
}
```

Then create a cursor loader that is used to retrieve the image path.

```
@Override 
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
    }; 
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, imageUri, projection, null, null, null);

    return cursorLoader; 
}
```

When the cursor loader is finished it uses the retrieved data to update the UI.

```
@Override 
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    if (data != null) {
        int columnIndex = data.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

        data.moveToFirst();
        imagePath = data.getString(columnIndex);
    } else { 
        imagePath = imageUri.getPath(); 
    } 

    setupImageView(); 
}
```

Comment: How to start an activity for result?? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result-on-android)