# Get image path from an ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am trying to get the image path string from an imageView. 
The imageView is charged using a string path store in SQLite db.
When I modify an item of my Db in some fiels other than image path one, I can't read back the path from imageView to correctly update the db. So the field image path become null after any kind of update.

In code, when I click the save button I call the saveProduct() method:

```
private void saveProduct() {
    // Read from input field
    //Use trim to eliminate leading or trailing white space
    String nameString = mNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String qtyString = mQtyEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String priceString = mPriceEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String mailString = mEmailEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String phoneString = mPhoneEditText.getText().toString().trim();

    // Check if this is a new product or an existing one
    if (mcurrentProdUri == null &&
            TextUtils.isEmpty(nameString) && TextUtils.isEmpty(qtyString)
            && TextUtils.isEmpty(priceString)&& TextUtils.isEmpty(mailString)
            && TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneString)) {
        return;
    }

    //Create a ContentValues object to populate the database
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(InventoryContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME, nameString);
    values.put(InventoryContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_QTY, qtyString);
    values.put(InventoryContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_PRICE, priceString);
    values.put(InventoryContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_EMAIL, mailString);
    values.put(InventoryContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PHONE, phoneString);
    values.put(InventoryContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_PIC, picPath);

    //Determine if this is a new product or not by checking if mCurrentProdUri is null or not
    if (mcurrentProdUri == null) {

        Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(InventoryContract.ProductEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);

        // check if newUri is null or not
        if (newUri == null){
            //Show an error toast message
            Toast.makeText(this, "There has been an error inserting a new product", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            //Otherwise show a successful addition message
            Toast.makeText(this, "A new product has been added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    } else {
        //Otherwise if this is an existing product proceed updating it with new data

        int rowsAffected = getContentResolver().update(mcurrentProdUri, values, null, null);

        if (rowsAffected == 0) {
            // If no rows were affected show error toast message
            Toast.makeText(this, "There has been an error in updating the product", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // Otherwise the update was successful and we can show the related Toast message
            Toast.makeText(this, "The product has been updated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```

I already read all related posts, but I really don't know how I can make the method read the imageView to get out the related image path (or Uri)

Many thanks for support

Comment: An `ImageView` does not know where the image came from. You need to remember this information in some other way, such as via a separate field in your activity or fragment.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the quick answer. I load the data on the UI using  getLoaderManager().initLoader(EXISTING_PROD_LOADER, null, this);, I suppose I have to store the path data here?

Comment: @CommonsWare! I've solved adding some logic in OnLoadFinished() as suggested in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424624/using-cursorloader-with-loadermanager-to-retrieve-images-from-android-apps. Thanks for putting me in the right track!

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the uri at the activity/fragment level before you load the imageview as it's not the responsibility of a regular `ImageView` to remember it's source.

You can, however, build an extended ImageView that is responsible for that if it helps your case:

```
class MyImageView extends ImageView {

    private Uri mImageUri;

    public MyImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageURI(@Nullable Uri uri) {
        super.setImageURI(uri);
        mImageUri = uri;
    }

    public Uri getImageUri(){
        return mImageUri;
    }
}
```

If you do go that route, you have to take view state saving into consideration during config changes or you may lose that uri.