# How do Gallery app load Images and Videos so fast?

Tags: android, image, performance, video, loading

I am trying to load all the Images and Videos present on the user's device but the problem is that on some device the loading is very slow and takes some time. And also the loading speed is further decreased if the phone is running many apps at the same time. Whereas the gallery app which is preinstalled loads the Images and Videos at much faster speed (at all times).

This is how I am loading the Images and Videos-

```
public void getImages(Context context) {

        File Image_File;
        final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};

        String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED ;

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                null, orderBy);

        if (cursor != null)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            final int dataColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
             {
                Image_File = new File(cursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));
                            images.add(0,Image_File);

              }
         }
}

    public void getVideos(Context context) {

        File Video_File;

        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media._ID };
        String orderBy =  MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED;

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                null, orderBy);

        if (cursor!=null)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            final int dataColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Video_File = new File(cursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));

                            videos.add(0,Video_File);

            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestion on how to improve the speed of loading or any suggestion on how to make this code more efficient would be really appreciated and grateful

Comment: "on some device the loading is very slow and takes some time" -- use method tracing to determine exactly where you are spending your time.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the Answer. Can you please provide an example of how to perform the method tracing.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler.html

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the link. Will look into it and update.

Comment: @propoLis Still working on this issue.

Comment: ok I've just wondered that the library is beneficial?

Comment: @propoLis The library is very useful not only for this purpose but will also be helpful to me for other purposes. It will take some time for me to study the whole library as I am not familiar with Android development.

Comment: good luck @Rahulrr2602 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this kind of project. Checking the link will benefit you a lot:

https://github.com/andriyadi/AndroidMediaChooser

Comment: Thank You very much. Will look into that and update you.

Comment: Went through the library found it very useful. Thanks for making the library. Will use it for learning other things also. Will contact you if I get stuck with anything. Just wanted to confirm that since the library is open source can the codes in that library be used by me in my app?

Comment: Yes this library is open source and you can implement your project like your wanted

Answer (score 3):

Consider running your query using [`CursorLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) to prevent blocking UI thread and obtaining live updates. I think answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424624/using-cursorloader-with-loadermanager-to-retrieve-images-from-android-apps) might be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using an AsyncTask to load the Images and Videos. Will using this method decrease the loading time?